# Determine the probability that the total loss $X + Y >2$

Tags: probability

I am unsure of how many questions I can post, but I just posted one a few minutes ago, if I can't post them so quickly let me know and I'll delete this.

Here is the question,

X and Y are random losses with the following joint density function:

$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^x & \text{for }\,0<x<y<2 \\ 0 & \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$

Determine the probability that the total loss $X + Y$ is greater than 2.

I thought that I could do $P(X+Y>2)=P(Y>2-x)$ so the integration would be $$\int_0^2\int_{2-x}^2({3\over4})^xdydx$$ but I get a number larger than 1 when I do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are forgetting that $0<x<y<2$. So with $y+x>2$, you are integrating over this triangular region

[image]

and not this one (the one you are trying to do).

[image]

Notice that the PDF is actually $0$ over half of this region.